# Developing checkboxes in databound WPF treeview leafs

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview, checkbox, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have the next WPF treeview:

```
        <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,0,0,32" Name="tvProductos" Width="158">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Securities" IsExpanded="True" FontWeight="Bold">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Country" Name="Country" FontWeight="Normal" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Currency" Name="Currency" FontWeight="Normal" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Type" Name="Type" FontWeight="Normal" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="ISIN" Name="ISIN" FontWeight="Normal" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Description" Name="Description" FontWeight="Normal" />
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Issuer" IsExpanded="True" FontWeight="Bold">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Name" Name="IssuerName" FontWeight="Normal" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Type" Name="IssuerType" FontWeight="Normal" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Market" Name="IssuerMarket" FontWeight="Normal" />
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
```

This structure is fixed. Then I bind low level TreeViewItems using code like this:

```
        Country.ItemsSource = (from d in db.PAISES
                               join p in db.PRODUCTOS on d.IDPAIS equals p.IDPAIS
                               select d.NOMBREPAIS).Distinct();
        Currency.ItemsSource = (from d in db.DIVISAS
                                join p in db.PRODUCTOS on d.IDDIVISA equals p.IDDIVISA
                                select d.NOMBREDIVISA).Distinct();
        Type.ItemsSource = (from d in db.TIPOSPRODUCTO
                            join p in db.PRODUCTOS on d.IDTIPOPRODUCTO equals p.IDTIPOPRODUCTO
                            select d.NOMBRETIPOPRODUCTO).Distinct();
        ...
```

The problem is that I need to add one checkbox on each node (low and high level). I have been looking for a solution and the best one is using HierarchicalDataTemplate. But I never found a example with fixed and dynamic nodes at same time. I tried with several examples but I couldn't solve it.

Can you help me on this?

Thank you in advance.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'd do it is using a helper class that represents the items that can be checked (some would call it a "view model"):

```
public class SelectableItem
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

This allows you to specify a `DataTemplate` for this specific type:

```
<TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,0,0,32" Name="tvProductos" Width="158">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SelectableItem}" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Securities" IsExpanded="True" FontWeight="Bold">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Country" Name="Country" FontWeight="Normal" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Currency" Name="Currency" FontWeight="Normal" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Type" Name="Type" FontWeight="Normal" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="ISIN" Name="ISIN" FontWeight="Normal" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Description" Name="Description" FontWeight="Normal" />
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Issuer" IsExpanded="True" FontWeight="Bold">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Name" Name="IssuerName" FontWeight="Normal" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Type" Name="IssuerType" FontWeight="Normal" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Market" Name="IssuerMarket" FontWeight="Normal" />
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

All you need to do is modify slightly your data sources:

```
Country.ItemsSource = (from d in db.PAISES
                       join p in db.PRODUCTOS on d.IDPAIS equals p.IDPAIS
                       select new SelectableItem { Label = d.NOMBREPAIS }).Distinct();
```

And that should do the trick.

Comment: Ok, it works! Thank you very much. Now, How I Can retrieve selected nodes?

Comment: There would be about a 1000 ways to do it, depending on how your app is architectured, one way would be with something like this: `Country.ItemsSource.Cast<SelectableItem>().Where(i => i.IsSelected)` ;)